# Is it possible to force that all class public methods return the same type with typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am building some helper classes that operate on or get some specific DOM element types.

So I have for example an `HTMLDivElementHelper` all public methods should return `HTMLDivElement`.

Those methods contain at least one params but they can also contain 2.

I am trying to force this with an interface or similar but I can not find how to do it.

If I use `class MyHelper implements Record<string, () => HTMLDivElement>`  Typescript complains that `Property 'setValue' of type '(selector: string) => HTMLDivElement' is not assignable to 'string' index type '() => HTMLDivElement'.(2411)`

[Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeAJApiADsgTtAlgWzRGT2QDsAXGAJWWAHtMATAHgnMx1IHMAaaACgCU0ALwA%20aIgAqsADIARHADcAokRIUJAbwBQ0aAG0A1gC5obDtwC6ZoaInS5i1erLkA3Dr3nk5AGpgIACuyPwQqLTkDGYWnFyCZo4KymrEbtC6%20vqYvkGYpNCMdMBBGuQAdMA5YOTIqWX8AOSMyo2CnvoAvl5ZPuRSyGxhEcBRmDHscXx0aOQ4dKQQZlozcwtL5pPcnQmSMskuaRQZ3tm5%20YXFpW6V1bX1bk0tSm0d0N3dOvSL5NB4SKgMNgRNBSMgAO5wAHoLBCTxAA)

Is this possible?

Comment: You don't even need to implement `Record`, having `[key: string]: (...arg: any[]) => HTMLDivElement` in the class is enough. The drawback is that `myHelper.whatever()` will be perfectly legitimate code.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WPx3zW) meet your needs?  Can you explain what the restrictions on parameters are?  You say "Those methods contain at least one params but they can also contain 2." but that doesn't specify what the types of the params are, nor whether the compiler should complain if you write a function accepting 0 parameters.   Anyway this approach allows you to write non-function properties freely (like `nonMethod`).  If that works for you I can write up an answer; otherwise please [edit] the code in the question to demonstrate unsatisfied use cases.

Comment: @jcalz that is exactly what I needed! In the final code I will eventually replace `selector: string` with another interface like `selector: UnionOfSupportedSelectors` but that also works with your typescript playground. Thank you! I will wait for your answer to accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you'd like to allow your class to have members that *aren't* functions, then you can't use a string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), nor can you say `implements Record<string, XXX>` because [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) is the same as an index signature when your key type is `string`.

---

Instead, you can come up with a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `CheckMethods<T>` that acts as a  *constraint* on your class.  The idea is that you write `class MyHelper implements CheckMethods<MyHelper> { /* ... */ }`, where `CheckMethods<MyHelper>` will evaluate to something compatible with `MyHelper` if and only if all the methods (well, function-valued members) are of the type you want them to be.  This sort of self-referential constraint is known as ["F-bounded quantification"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification).  Here's a possible implementation:

```
type CheckMethods<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ?
  ((selector: string, options: any) => HTMLDivElement) : T[K] }
```

Here `CheckMethods<T>` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where each property key `K` from `T` is mapped to a new property type.  The old property type `T[K]` is checked with a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to see if it's a `Function` or not.  If it's not, we just map it to itself, `T[K]`, which will always be true.  If it *is* a function, then we map it to a specific function type `(selector: string, options: any) => HTMLDivElement`, which will work with any function of up to two parameters of the same type (see [the documentation for function compatiblity](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions) for more information.

Let's see it in action:

```
class MyHelper implements CheckMethods<MyHelper> {

  nonMethod = 123; // okay

  setValue(selector: string): HTMLDivElement { // okay
    return document.createElement('div');
  }

  setTest(selector: string, options: { options: string }): HTMLDivElement { // okay
    return document.createElement('div');
  }

  badParameter(selector: number): HTMLDivElement { // error!
     return document.createElement("div");
  } 

  badReturn(selector: string) { return 3 } // error!

}
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgFhAxgawLIWHA9gEwM4A8AKgHxQC8UA3lANoDSUAlgHZTIQhYBmURAugC4+DflAgAPYBBb4oAMQCuLRMCZY2AfgBQUKAAp9eCABskwLACdheYJdYBzADRQsYNRrzCAhixABKCjIACSJUABkAESYANwBRMwBbGWBA4SJRKABfbW1EE288PChUEGDTSEtmRLAklOL4JDQMbHwCUvKTSrIqXL0WDXRMXAooAEYAJgBmAG4oAHp512RvED6oY2AANW8TRQgjU3MrGztHf2FQiOj4upZgal09KEsMRUs2HCxERWT7gDpEK9vNIEhA-sB9AByHCxKH+GZPHJPTZECC2Q5mVQnDZnFjOVzudQsLzUQkeEmnez47IXKBXKKxMEQx7PF5vD5QL4-CGA4Ggu6QmFwhFI9YAI28OAACt5LN5ktJLJjjtYoCxfuKIJY6QybsyUqznq9gO9Pt9fik+RAQRADfd9AAiWExR2ivTIvSSnAAJQ5LBV2LVtmpDkCNBNZqgU2yuWRiE8D0SZQq2tGLAgAHcSimutr9KKgA)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

It compiles but I'm not sure that this is what you are looking for.

```
type MethodSignature = (selector: string, options?:{options: string}) => HTMLDivElement;

class MyHelper implements Record<string, MethodSignature> {
  [k: string]: MethodSignature;

  setValue(selector: string): HTMLDivElement {
    return document.createElement('div');
  }

  setTest(selector: string, options?: {options: string}): HTMLDivElement {
    return document.createElement('div');
  }
}

const myHelper = new MyHelper();
```